# read json data with resource in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I read json data with $resource and I am so confused is it result just show first word
ex: json data's value is function1 and result will be f ?

there is my code

```
experiment.directive('groupsControl', function(){
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  transclude: false,
  template: '<div class="left"><div ng-repeat="group in children"><section-control sections="group.data"/></div></div>'
}})


.directive('sectionControl', function(){
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  transclude: false,
  scope: { items:'=sections'},

  template: '<div ng-repeat="section in items" ng-include="getIncludeFile(section)">'+
            '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.getIncludeFile = function(section) {
        return section.data + ".html";
    }       
  }
}})
```

there is my json data

```
{ 
"name": "test", "children":[
{"data": "function1" }, 
{"data": "function2" }, 
{"data": "function3" }  ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template in groupsControl directive should be:

```
template: '<div class="left"><div ng-repeat="group in children"><section-control sections="group"/></div></div>'
```

Comment: would you tell me more detail, I want to know why is sections="group"

Comment: That is because you were already sending "group.data" from groupsControl directive and therefore there was no need of doing "section.data" in sectionControl. Does your code work now?